# Виснет форма при GET запросе

Tags: c#, get

Подскажите человеку, не очень разбирающемуся в запросах. У меня есть несколько, подобных этим, запросов.

```
public string Get_Task_Instance(string id)
    {
        WebRequest rq = WebRequest.Create("адрес" + id);
        rq.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic " + auth_base64("login:pass"));
        rq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse sq = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(sq.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            get_tasks_instance = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        if (sq.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK") return get_tasks_instance;
        else return "ERROR";
    }


public void Complete_Task_Ozn(string id)
    {

            WebRequest rq = WebRequest.Create("адрес" + id + "/complete");
            rq.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic " + auth_base64("login:pass"));
            rq.Method = "POST";
            string data = "{  }";
            byte[] bytearray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            rq.ContentType = "application/json";
            rq.ContentLength = bytearray.Length;
            using (Stream dS = rq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dS.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            }


    }
```

Проблема в том, что, если их использовать, то на некотором использовании (более 4-ех одновременно) приложение виснет, под отладкой приложение начинает виснуть на этой строке:

```
HttpWebResponse sq = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать. Спасибо.

Comment: Устанавливаете Fiddler, смотрите в нем висят ли запросы, если запросы тормозят на сервере - идете к разработчикам сервера.

Comment: А еще вроде есть встроенные в дотнет лимиты на коннект к 1 хосту.

Comment: @vitidev, чиво 0_o

Comment: @Kamushek [By default, an application using the HttpWebRequest class uses a maximum of two persistent connections to a given server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections)

Comment: Но это не "встроенные в .Net" :D

Comment: @Kamushek У нас видимо разное понимание слова "встроено".

Comment: @vitidev спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, форма виснет т.к. ты ждешь ответа с сервера, что блокирует твою форму.

Делай асинхронный запрос и сами методы сделай асинхронными.

Или делай вызов метода в  НЕ-UI потоке.

Comment: Не подскажете как это осуществить?

Comment: вместо 'GetResponse()' используй 'GetResponseAsync().Result;' -- и вообще где возможно используй асинхронные вызовы методов в даном случае...  и сами методы из код семпла сделай асинхронными используя модификаторы async; а в методе где вызываются эти методы используй await при вызове.

Comment: Огромное спасибо